# Python: Subtract two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have two DataFrames:

```
df1:
            A    B    C 
Date
2022-01-01  0    100  0
2022-01-04  50   0    0
2022-02-08  0    0    200

df2:
            A    B    C 
Date
2022-01-01  0    200  0
2022-01-02  0    200  0
2022-02-03  0    200  0
2022-01-04  50   200  0
2022-01-05  100  200  0
2022-02-06  100  200  0
2022-01-07  100  200  0
2022-01-08  100  200  100
2022-02-09  100  200  300
```

I want to subtract df2 from df1 to get the following

```
df:
            A    B    C 
Date
2022-01-01  0    100  0
2022-01-02  0    200  0
2022-02-03  0    200  0
2022-01-04  50   200  0
2022-01-05  100  200  0
2022-02-06  100  200  0
2022-01-07  100  200  0
2022-01-08  100  200  100
2022-02-09  100  200  300
```

However, `df1.subtract(df2)` results in empty cells for the indexes that are not in df1. Is there another to do this, preserving all other indexes in df2?

EDIT: Fixed values in `df`

Comment: `DataFrame.subtract(other, axis='columns', level=None, fill_value=None)` check more at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html)

Comment: `df.subtract()` has an argument for `axis`, have you tried changing that? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `fill_value`:

```
df1.subtract(df2, fill_value=0)
```

However, given the provided output, it looks more like you want an addition and to restrict the index to that of `df2`:

```
df2.add(df1.reindex_like(df2), fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
                A      B      C
Date                           
2022-01-01    0.0  300.0    0.0
2022-01-02    0.0  200.0    0.0
2022-02-03    0.0  200.0    0.0
2022-01-04  100.0  200.0    0.0
2022-01-05  100.0  200.0    0.0
2022-02-06  100.0  200.0    0.0
2022-01-07  100.0  200.0    0.0
2022-01-08  100.0  200.0  100.0
2022-02-09  100.0  200.0  300.0
```